# How to manage more than 200 microservice with Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i would want to know how do you manage your service with Helm ?

I already know that we are going to have more than **200 microservices**. *How to manage them easily* ?

Each microservice with is own yaml files (**deployment,service,ingress ,values** etc..)
 or **one several large** (deployment,ingress, etc.. )yaml files **for all** microservices and i push the values yaml file with the specific params for the application.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest aiming for an umbrella chart that includes lots of subcharts for the individual services. You can deploy each chart individually but using a single umbrella makes it easier to deploy the whole setup consistently to different environments.

Perhaps some microservices will be similar enough that for them you could use the same chart with different parameters (maybe including docker image parameter) but you'll have to work through them to see whether you can do that. You can include the same chart as a dependency multiple times within an umbrella chart to represent different services.

Ideally you also want a chart for a service to be individually-deployable so you can deploy and check that service in isolation. To do this you would give each chart its own resources including its own Ingress. But you might decide that for the umbrella chart you prefer to disable the Ingresses in the subcharts and put in a single fan-out Ingress for everything - that comes down to what works best for you.